# How to get all the content within an HTML tag using XPath in R

Tags: r, xpath

I've seen other posts for how to do this in java but sadly, I only know R

I want to get all the content (tags, attributes, values) verbatim contained in a tag, including the content of child tags. I thought I could do something like

```
a = xpathSApply(html, "//span[@class = 'class name']/node()", ????)
```

But then I realized I don't know any functions which get the entire content of your path and not just the attributes or just the text. How would I do this?

Comment: Graham - happy to help. Could you make a example of html you'd like to parse, what the result is, and what you want the result to look like?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether that is applicable in your use-case, but have you tried to work with the library xml2?

```
content <- read_xml( html )
nodes <- xml_find_all(content, xpath)   # or xml_find_one if you want only the first result
```

From there you can do all kinds of things using `xml_text()`, `xml_attrs()`, `xml_name()`, `xml_children()`, ...

To really just retrieve the complete content, `a <- paste(nodes[[1]])` would do I guess...